# Ability to close questions as dupe even if there are no answers

Tags: feature-request

Just because a question has no answer doesn't mean it isn't a duplicate, so why can't we close them like that?

For example:

[How to know if a page loaded via iframe is within sandbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34043278/how-to-know-if-a-page-loaded-via-iframe-is-within-sandbox)

[Detect if JavaScript is Executing In a Sandboxed Iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435076/detect-if-javascript-is-executing-in-a-sandboxed-iframe)

These are clear duplicates but we can't close either as a dupe since neither has been answered. Clearly if there is an answered question then both should be closed as dupes of that one but that is not the case here.

Comment: What happens when another users ask a similar question and it is a better question overall and more likely to attract an answer but it gets closed? Part of the reason for requiring an answer (on non meta sites) is to allow for a better question to get an answer and then close the other questions as a duplicate.

Comment: @JoeW In such an example it would just being case as the wrong duplicate being closed.  You should always close the less useful question as a duplicate of the more useful question, not the newest as a duplicate of the oldest.

Comment: Are you still able to close duplicate from the same author even without an answer on either question?  Obviously, this corner case won't cover most situations.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: I don't have a link handy to such a case right now, but yes, you can. That exact scenario has happened rather often in the [c] and [c++] tags for a while now...

Comment: Related on Meta.SE: [We should be able to close questions as duplicates of any question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165928)

Comment: @user193661: On metas? Or by the same user? Both are specific exceptions to the usual rule.

Comment: If it's not clear which question is "better", you should possibly close the older question as a duplicate of the newer one.

Comment: I ran into this case today... I believe the user opened a second account and asked the same question ([#1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105079/bug-two-tables-scroll-widget) & [#2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120075/table-sorter-scroll-widget-bug)). The only way I found to deal with that was to flag one question for a moderator.

Answer (score 9):

When one of the questions has an answer, closing it as a duplicate serves a purpose: telling the OP (and others that stumble on the question) that his/her question already has an answer in the other question, and he should read for more info there. When neither of the questions has an answer, what purpose does closing it as a duplicate have? Simply letting the OP know that others don't know the answer either?

Comment: Not at all, there are many uses for it. It draws attention to the fact that multiple people have the same problem, it concentrates and discussions and attempts to find the solution that may be happening in one place, and it means that if you need a solution to the problem then you only need to monitor one question rather than needing to monitor a potentially unlimited number of them.

Comment: @TimB: All of that can be done via a simple comment (e.g., "See discussions others are having on the same question here") on the question at hand; why do you need to close anything?

Comment: And that's what I did in the case of these questions. But why do you need to leave them open? What value does an additional open answer that's a clear duplicate, that splits any potential discussion, means more questions might need to be monitored, etc add to the site? It's just increasing the amount of noise when we should be trying to increase the amount of signal.

Comment: @TimB: Actually, that's why I think it shouldn't be closed as a duplicate; if it's closed as a duplicate and it's a bad question (i.e., it attracts downvotes or at least doesn't attract upvotes), it won't be deleted by the roomba (the roomba will not delete duplicates regardless of score). In any event, the older question wasn't likely to see any more discussion (in your example, the older question hadn't had any comment - until your comment and bounty - for 7 months); just track the new one.

Comment: @R_Kapp: "the roomba will not delete duplicates regardless of score" — [sure it does](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40566/should-i-use-had-in-the-following-sentence) (ELL 2k link). That is (or was) a year-old, zero-scored dupe with no answers. It won't delete 9-day wonders, though, you're right.

Comment: @R_Kapp If one of them receives an answer, we'll need to close the other as a dupe at that point anyway. Why wait? Why not take care of it up front when people are paying attention to it?

Comment: _"When neither of the questions has an answer, what purpose does closing it as a duplicate have?"_ Closing as dupe is not just to "help" the OP. In fact, it's not really about that at all. It's about curatorship. It's about tidying up the site, keeping it clean. We do not need two copies of the same question, with distinct sets of answers. We only want _one_. Dupe closing achieves that. End of story.

Answer (score 6):

In such a specific case where they are clearly unique and useful, but a duplicate of each other, I'd flag to close with a custom reason explaining exactly that, and to point OP and later visitors to the oldest/best written/highest scoring question.

Then add a comment for the OP that they can upvote and favorite that question, and maybe add a bounty.

This to prevent fragmentation, what duplicates are for.

Answer (score 6):

It's a shame we have to select one or other question formulation as a duplicate of the other.  I've always thought that the model should be more like

```
                         +-------------+
+-----------+        1..*| Question    |
|           |<>----------| Formulation |
| Question  |            +-------------+
| Page      |            
|           |            +-------------+
|           |<>----------| Answer      | 
+-----------+        0..*|             |
                         +-------------+
```

in other words, we should be able to see both formulations of the question on the same page.