# Unable to flag two extremely similar questions as duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Those two questions

[Odoo 10 - Using triggers on form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49643932/odoo-10-using-triggers-on-form)

[Using database triggers on forms in Odoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49645363/using-database-triggers-on-forms-in-odoo)

were posted with 99% the same content.

I wanted to flag the 2nd one as duplicate of the 1st one, but the system won't allow me to do that.

> This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer

Is the system supposed to be like that?

I just think this is plagiarism and flagging questions as duplicate should work even if the questions are not upvoted or accepted answer. Or maybe there should be another option, e.g Flagging as plagiarism?

Note: I think my question is very close to this [one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311683/ability-to-close-questions-as-dupe-even-if-there-are-no-answers), but it's not. That question mentioned about 2 different questions while this case, the 2 questions are exactly/lexically/technically the same.

Comment: ... Am puzzled how the concept of _plagiarism_ can be applied to questions.. If two have  same questions, they are either working on the same project/assignment etc.. or dupe accounts (perhaps not in this case) to get more attention

Comment: Always a good reason to flag for moderator attention, they can see more and determine whether this is an impatient user that is abusing the site with multiple accounts.

Comment: I would flag for mod attention. They do seem fishy.

Comment: @SurajRao You're right, I was not able to find a better word than 'plagiarism'.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Thanks for your title edit, that's much clearer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, plagiarism cases should be mod-flagged with your explanation as to why you believe it is plagiarism.

However, when I'm looking at these, I doubt it is actually plagiarism -- that is, trying to pass of another's work as your own -- because that doesn't make too much sense for a question, because there's not really any work to copy from; it's not a good enough quality question with anything that merits copying.

My guess at what is going on here is that either Mingg Lex and shillow willer are either the same person or are members of the same group having this issue, and they posted the first question, then after two hours with no answer, posted again in hopes of getting an answer.

The good news is that this second case is still a good reason to flag a moderator, as they can check the IPs to see if they are the same or coming from a very similar geographic location and know if that's actually what is going on and delete the duplicate question, or they can investigate if something else weird is going on with those accounts and deal with it accordingly. So raising a mod flag would be more appropriate than this Meta question.