# Why can't I click to upvote during Review triage if question consensus is "Looks OK"

Tags: support, bug, review-queues

I was going through my daily review of "triage" and ran across something I have seen for the first time when the question consensus "Looks OK" I can't upvote the question as the 3rd reviewer:

[image]

As you can see, there is a blue box around upvote after I click it, but no vote registers on the click. Only that blue box appears. If I open the question in another page and click the upvote as a normal user, it upvotes. Is this a bug? I am using Chrome as my browser. To note, this happened on multiple questions I tried to upvote. When I open the page in another tab after I have clicked to upvote, no upvote appears (in case it was a visual display bug). [This post clearly states that if you are the reviewer that gets the opportunity to vote do so](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue/295674#295674)!

**EDIT**

A further note, I have now experienced this behavior on Mozilla and Edge as well. The same blue box appears around the arrow when I am the 3rd reviewer to choose "Looks OK" and I try to upvote, but I must open the question as a separate page in a new tab in order to actually vote on the question.

Comment: Is this new? I have been reviewing for the last few months and when the consensus is "Looks OK" it has previously allowed me to vote on the question inside the review before going to next.

Comment: [See this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311683/ability-to-close-questions-as-dupe-even-if-there-are-no-answers) as to why my question should not be closed as a duplicate. I do now know that there is in fact a question very similar to mine, also with no answers. I do think I went into some more detail such as browser and upvoting.

Comment: I am not sure if that post applies to bug reports (or to Meta posts in general) but I agree that your post has more details and it is clearer here that this is in fact a bug. I wouldn't object if the other post is closed/linked as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: This is still an issue that does not seem to have received any attention on either post.